# How to write the code for listeners in TestNG?

Tags: reporting, testng, listeners

I want to know how can i use listeners in my java code? Also what changes are to made in the xml file if i want to incorporate the listeners? I added org.testng.ITestNGListener then too the program is throwing errors?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any specific questions that are not covered by the documentation:

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging

?

Comment: Getting better reports/logs , is this the only use of **@Listeners** annotations, if not can you help us by giving some example, how can we use this annotations in scenarios